# OSError 10057 when trying to use pip on win7

Tags: python, pip

I've installed python 3.4 on win7, but can't get pip to work, I keep getting the following error:

```
pip install django
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(10057, '(when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied', None, 10057, None))': /pypi
```

...

```
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(10057
```

Comment: Could you check if you have any internet connection problems?

Comment: What Python distribution did you install? From python.org?